Faces navigation case to a Servlet
Having two pages page1 and page2 in a web application.
Page page1 is a facelet based on an .xhtml file and page2 is generated by a servlet.
Let's assume page1.xhtml looks like this:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="jakarta.faces.html"
      xmlns:f="jakarta.faces.core"
      >
    <h:head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:button outcome="yolo" value="move on"/>
    </h:body>
</html>

And for the sake of simplicity let page2 be generated from the following servlet:
package tests;

import jakarta.servlet.ServletException;
import jakarta.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;

@WebServlet(urlPatterns = "/abc")
public class DummySrv extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        
        resp.getWriter().write("abc");
    }
    
}

I have also added a navigation rule to the faces-config.xml as follows:
<navigation-rule>
  <from-view-id>
    /page1.xhtml
  </from-view-id>
  <navigation-case>
    <from-outcome>
      yolo
    </from-outcome>
    <to-view-id>
      /abc
    </to-view-id>
  </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>

How can I redirect from page1 to page2 ?
Currently the navigation rule adds .xhtml extension so by clicking the "move on" button on page1 I get 404.

Apparently, simple mapping a servlet to a path with .xhtml extension does the job.
For example:
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = "/abc.xhtml")

